# Can I boot from Snow Leopard DVD on 'normal' pc?

Tags: startup

Just wondering if I have a copy of of snow leopard 10.6, if I put it in a typical pc that runs windows will it boot or do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not boot. Sharing knowledge about making it boot is against the rules here.

Comment: I had a dvd that i thought had os x on it. It seems to ignore it when I switch on my mac pro with it in the drive, so I was just checking to see if I could verify it was the disc not the mac pro at fault by booting it on a dell laptop someone has.